# How to wrap functions with the `--wrap` option correctly?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning, linker-flags

The man page of gcc 6.3 says:

```
--wrap=symbol
           Use a wrapper function for symbol.  Any undefined reference to
           symbol will be resolved to "__wrap_symbol".  Any undefined
           reference to "__real_symbol" will be resolved to symbol.
           ...
           If you link other code with this file using --wrap malloc, then all
           calls to "malloc" will call the function "__wrap_malloc" instead.
           The call to "__real_malloc" in "__wrap_malloc" will call the real
           "malloc" function.
```

So I created a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() {
    printf("foo\n");
    return 0;
}

int __wrap_foo() {
    printf("wrap foo\n");
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    printf("foo:");foo();
    printf("wrapfoo:");__wrap_foo();
    printf("realfoo:");__real_foo();
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it with:

```
gcc main.c -Wl,--wrap=foo -o main
```

This gave me a warning:

```
main.c:18:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘__real_foo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("realfoo:");__real_foo();
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Well going on. Now I would suggest an output like this:

```
foo:wrap foo
wrapfoo:wrap foo
realfoo:foo
```

Instead I get this:

```
foo:foo
wrapfoo:wrap foo
realfoo:foo
```

I hope the thing is clear. I am confused about the warning. Normally the `__real` function should be linked by the linker to `foo()`. Furthermore a call to `foo()` should be linked to `__wrap_foo`. But the output showes, that `foo()` is being executed instead.

How to use `--wrap` correctly?

Comment: It did work. But because you have a single translation unit, and `foo` is present, the call to `foo` is not an **undefined reference** to `foo`.

Comment: Well, I do not understand. The output of the example above seems wrong to me. `foo()` should output `"wrap foo"`! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are ignoring the "undefined reference" **requirement**.

Comment: Wohooo, that's it! ...going now to compose a complete answer...

Comment: personal opinion: The correct way to use the `--wrap` stuff is not at all. It is a horrible workaround for when you just must link with certain libraries where you don't have the source and you have to do terrible things like this to make it work. It's a last ditch effort to save your sanity when you're out of all other options (including talking to the library vendor, then talking to your boss and threatening to quit if you have to keep using a bad library that requires hacks like this).

Comment: That's all right with me. I'm using `--wrap` just to create some stubs and mock objects when there is no other choice to implementing some unit tests.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As StoryTeller told me, I ignored the "undefined reference" requirement which I already posted above:

> ... Any **undefined reference** to symbol will be resolved to "__wrap_symbol".  Any **undefined reference** to "__real_symbol" will be resolved to symbol.

To use the `--wrap` option I rearranged my code example like this:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int foo();
extern int __real_foo();

int __wrap_foo() {
    printf("wrap foo\n");
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    printf("foo:");foo();
    printf("wrapfoo:");__wrap_foo();
    printf("realfoo:");__real_foo();
    return 0;
}
```

foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo() {
    printf("foo\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile:

```
gcc main.c foo.c -Wl,--wrap=foo -o main
```

And the the amazing output after running `./main`:

```
foo:wrap foo
wrapfoo:wrap foo
realfoo:foo
```

The trick is (correct me if I am wrong) that the reference of `foo()` and `__real_foo()` is not defined at compile time. I. E. they have **undefined references" which is the requierement for the linker to link `foo()` to `__wrap_foo()` and `__real_foo()` to `foo()`.

Comment: A "automatic" way to define the extern symbol is to use `extern typeof (myfunction) __real_myfunction;`