# Wrapping a function

Tags: c, gcc, ld

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444052/how-to-wrap-functions-with-the-wrap-option-correctly), we can wrap a function using the `-Wl,--wrap` switch.
Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __wrap_f()
{
        puts("wrapped");
}

void f()
{
        puts("original");
}

int main(void)
{
        f();
}
```

The program was written to `a.c` and compiled as `gcc -Wl,--wrap=f a.c`. When I run the executable (using `./a.out`), I get `original` as the output.

My expectation was that on invoking `f()`, the wrapped version would be called and the program would print `wrapped`. Please let me know what I am missing here.

GCC version: 9.1.0

Comment: See the first comment on that question. In fact, look at the answers. It's exactly the same problem.

Comment: As mentioned in comments on and answers to the question you linked to, you are ignoreing the "undefined references" requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this'll work with a single translation unit.
AFAIK, the `f` function needs to be in a separate file.

This works for me (prints wrapped):

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

cat > main.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>

void __wrap_f()
{
        puts("wrapped");
}

void f();
int main(void)
{
        f();
}
EOF

cat > f.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
void f()
{
        puts("original");
}
EOF

gcc wrap.c f.c -Wl,--wrap=f && ./a.out
```

Comment: It works with a single TU, since the real `f()` won't be called.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kind of eagerly expecting the user to transition to actual wrapping (using `__real_f`) instead of a simple symbol replacement. Then an actual `f` will be needed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Like in the answer you mention, you are ignoring the fact that you need to have an *undefined reference* to `f()`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __wrap_f()
{
        puts("wrapped");
}

void f();

int main(void)
{
        f();
}
```