# Is it possible to wrap a member function of a C++ class?

Tags: c++, g++, ld

I'm trying to wrap a member function of a C++ class. I've successfully wrapped system functions such as *fstat*, so the GNU linker, ld, creates a reference to __wrap_fstat and the real *fstat* is called by __real_fstat, but I can't seem to wrap a class member function. Here's a simple example of a class. I'd like to wrap test().

Foo.hpp

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {};
    ~Foo() {};
    void test();
}
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.hpp"

void Foo::test()
{
    printf("test\n");
}
```

I've tried this

```
g++ -o foo Foo.o -Wl,--wrap=Foo::test
```

The linker doesn't produce an error, but test() isn't wrapped. Does anyone know how to wrap a C++ class member function?

Comment: I guess you have to provide the mangled function name to the link command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap functions with the \`--wrap\` option correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444052/how-to-wrap-functions-with-the-wrap-option-correctly)

Comment: @Klaus I know how to wrap non-member functions. I'm trying to wrap a class member function.

Comment: @Epsilon C++ has something called *function overloading* that does not exist in C.  So your example using `fstat` doesn't apply, since it is a C runtime function, not a C++ function, thus overloading doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, all symbols names got [mangled](https://blog.oakbits.com/how-to-mangle-and-demangle-a-c-method-name.html) to ensure uniqueness of the symbol names, when function names are overloaded, placed in classes or subclasses, inside namespaces, etc.

The linker has no knowledge of the C++ original symbol names and only handles mangled symbol names. So to wrap a C++ member function, you have to wrap the mangled function name.

**Foo.hpp**

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {};
    ~Foo() {};
    void test();
};
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <cstdio>

void Foo::test()
{
   printf("Original Foo:test(): this = %p\n", (void*)this);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" void __real__ZN3Foo4testEv(Foo* This);

extern "C" void __wrap__ZN3Foo4testEv(Foo* This)
{
    printf("Wrapped Foo:test(): this = %p\n", (void*)This);
    __real__ZN3Foo4testEv(This);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    printf("Address of foo: %p\n", (void*)&foo);
    foo.test();
}
```

Usage:

```
$ g++ -o foo main.cpp Foo.cpp -Wl,--wrap=_ZN3Foo4testEv; ./foo
Address of foo: 0xffffcc2f
Wrapped Foo:test(): this = 0xffffcc2f
Original Foo:test(): this = 0xffffcc2f
```

Note the signature of the wrapping function `__wrap__ZN3Foo4testEv`: it needs to be declared `extern "C"` to avoid itself to being mangled. And it has access to the `this` as the first implicit argument.
If you need to call the original function, the same apply for the declaration of the *real* function `__real__ZN3Foo4testEv`.

To find out the mangled name of a C++ function, there are several ways. One would consist of first building the project without wrapping, and creating a **map** file from the linker. In the map file, you should be able to find out the mangled name of the desired function.

Comment: When I call test() from main(), it calls the wrapped function as expected. However, if I call test() from another member functions (of Foo), it calls the real version instead of the wrapped function. Do you know why?

Comment: @Epsilon I guess that the compiler has inlined the call to `test` when you tried from the same class. It doesn't matter whether it is in the same class or not, but it can matter if called from the same *source file* (compilation unit). To be sure, you should put the implementation of `Foo::test()` in its own source file.