# How to wrap a function via CMakeLists.txt

Tags: gcc, cmake, zephyr-rtos

I am implementing some unit test for zephyr and I need to mock a function that is included in a file that I can not remove from the test. So I am trying to use the `-Wl,--wrap=symbol` flag to create a wrapper that is called instead.

At [GCC wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444052/how-to-wrap-functions-with-the-wrap-option-correctly) is shown that with a command `gcc main.c foo.c -Wl,--wrap=foo -o main` I would be able wrap `foo` function.

My problem is that Zephyr is mainly implemented with CMake and I am struggling to make it generate a call like that.
How can I set my CMakeLists.txt so that I can link to files and use the wrap function?

I tried the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(motion_monitor_test)

set(SOURCES
    file1_path.c
    file2_path.c
)
target_sources(app PRIVATE ${SOURCES})
target_compile_options(app PRIVATE "-Wl,--wrap=set_tx_power")
```

But instead of generating one call `gcc -Wl,--wrap=set_tx_power -o CMakeFiles/app.dir/file.c.obj -c file1_path.c file2_path.c`, it creates to separated calls: `gcc -Wl,--wrap=set_tx_power -o CMakeFiles/app.dir/file1.c.obj -c file1_path.c` and `gcc -Wl,--wrap=set_tx_power -o CMakeFiles/app.dir/file2.c.obj -c file2_path.c`.

Comment: `-Wl` denotes a **linker** option. Such options could be specified in CMake via `target_link_options` command. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532853/how-can-i-add-linker-flag-for-libraries-with-cmake).